# Linking a specific library with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

This may be a basic question, but how do you find what library you need to link against with gcc? I am trying to compile a shared library that uses `#include <signal.h>`, but when I try to use it, it gives me a CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE because it can't locate any of the symbols. 
I am assuming I have to link specifically against the library with the flag `-l` in gcc, but I don't know where/what that library is.

At a more broad example, `-ldl` links against `libdl.so`, what `-l` can I use to link against the `#include <signal.h>`?

EDIT:

```
soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1617): could not load library "mylib.so" needed by "/bin/test";
cause by soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol "signal" referenced by "mylib.so"...CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc -fPIC -c -g -o mylib.o mylib.c  
gcc -shared -o mylib.so mylib.o -ldl
```

Comment: Execute a library?

Comment: There is no procedure that will work in all cases, because the names of libraries have no systematic relationship with the names of their headers. There are tools that can help in some cases, such as `pkg-config`, but the library has to be coded to support them.  In the specific case of `signal.h`, you shouldn't need any special `-l` switches at all; either your problem is caused by something else, or your C library is broken.  In order for us to help you figure out what's really going on, please copy and paste the complete and unedited text of the error messages you got into your question.

Comment: You got some errors? Couldn't the contents of those error messages possibly be at least *somewhat relevant to the question*?!

Comment: The functions in the `<signal.h>` header are normally found in the standard C library that is automatically linked with your program.  The error you're seeing is unexpected, therefore.  Is it the `gcc -shared` command line that causes the trouble, or is it when you use the library in another program?  What is the command sequence used to create that other program?  Who wrote `soinfo_link_image()`?  Where is `linker.cpp`?  That's a C++ file; do you need to link with the C++ compiler (`g++` instead of `gcc`)?

Comment: The error happens when I try to call the library from another program.  Unfortunately I didn't create the other program, so I don't know the command sequence.  Also I don't know where linker.cpp is, I am using a cross compile toolchain to cross compile for an arm processor.

Comment: So, is your `mylib.c` code using `dlopen()` and friends, or is it this mysterious other application that's doing that?  If you're creating a plugin library of some sort that will be loaded by this other program, you need to ensure you follow the other program's rules for what it takes to make a loadable plugin.  Since there's a `linker.cpp` lurking around, I'm deeply suspicious that the problem is in C vs C++ linkage.  I'm not sure whether judicious use of `extern "C"` would resolve the problem, or whether using a C++ compiler would solve the problem.  Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: The `/bin/test` name is puzzling too; that's normally a system-provided executable that mimics the shell built-in `test` (aka `[`) command.  There's information missing which means that the question doesn't yet make sense to me.  You'll probably need to connect some dots for me to have a chance of understanding the problem.  Maybe others can help without the extra info.  Cross-compilation for ARM is not something I've done.  Your compiler isn't self-evidently a cross-compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a linker question than a GCC question.  Often, the library name is mentioned in the library documentation.  On GNU/Linux distributions, many libraries have `.pc` files for [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/).  If not, you can use commands such as

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/signal.h
```

and

```
rpm -qf /usr/include/signal.h
```

to find the `-dev`/`-devel` packages which provided the header file, and then proceed to look at

```
dpkg -L libc6-dev
```

or

```
rpm -ql glibc-devel
```

output to determine the name of the `.so` files used for linking.  Defined symbols can be viewed using `objdump -T`, `nm -Dg`, or `eu-readelf --symbols=.dynsym` (so many choices).